Reactor consumer for ConcurrentLinkedQueue
I am trying to create a reactive producer/consumer for a ConcurrentLinkedQueue queue using reactive.
A producer is adding elements to the ConcurrentLinkedQueue queue at its own pace.
The consumer should continuously listen/subscribe to the queue and if/when an element is available, it should emit the element and collect until the total number of elements polled so far reaches the maxSize or a maxTime Duration elapses, and then emit the List of elements all at once. The consumer should not complete/stop/block if there are no elements in the queue.
I have applied a bufferTimeout for the consumer so that the Flux emits the elements each time the buffer reaches a maximum size OR the maxTime Duration elapses.
consumer
Flux.<SpecificRecord>generate(sink -> {
          SpecificRecord specificRecord = <queue>.poll(); // or, <queue>.take() for LinkedBlockingQueue
          if (specificRecord != null) {
            sink.next(specificRecord);
          } else {
            sink.complete();
          }
        })
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .parallel()
        .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
        .sequential()
        .bufferTimeout(5, Duration.ofSeconds(10))
        .doOnError(throwable -> log.error("Error while sending event to File with error: [{}]", throwable.getMessage()))
        .repeat()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newSingle("queue-event-processor"))
        .subscribe(specificRecords -> {
          log.info("Sending events to S3 with size: [{}]", specificRecords.size());
//          s3FixedSizeRollingPolicy.convertToParquetAndUpload(specificRecords, FulfilmentAuditEventKey.getClassSchema(), FulfilmentAuditEvent.getClassSchema());
        });

The consumer above stops as soon as there are no elements in the queue. I tried using LinkedBlockingQueue as well but this is also not working. LinkedBlockingQueue does not execute the subscribe method at all. Most probably because it keeps blocking at take() call.

Are you forced to use a queue ? This use-case seems perfect for use of Sinks

@amanin Sinks may fail when multiple threads are writing to it, hence, using a concurrent queue.

Then you may want to take the time to read the official documentation I've linked.Its first section title is 4.7.1. Safely Produce from Multiple Threads by Using Sinks.One and Sinks.Many. It also provides an exemple (search for the sentence Multiple producer threads may concurrently generate data on the sink by doing the following:).

@amanin There seems to be a challenge with the sink approach. Multiple threads concurrently pushing to the sink lead to FAIL_NON_SERIALIZED error. Handling it requires retry using busy looping. This could pose an issue in the systems where multiple threads (10000 QPS) are trying to write to the sink.

You are not forced to use the busy looping. You can use your own failure handler, or craft a custom retry loop by using tryEmitNext instead of emitNext. Note that using a ConcurrentLinkedQueue as you try, you might end up with a busy looping anyway, because you have to retry polling until an element is available. And using a BlockingQueue introduces blocking operations in a non-blocking framework, which would likely cause other problems.

@amanin when we say "you might end up with a busy looping anyway, because you have to retry polling until an element is available", we are referring to the consumer which is running on a single thread, so, only one thread would be waiting. But when we talk about busy looping for producer, we are talking about 100s of threads that might be retrying. This would not be a challenge? The idea is to use a construct that behaves some what like Kafka. Producers can produce parallelly without blocking/waiting.
